# best practice to use text-align: right when using a right-to-left language

Tags: css

suppose the project is in a right-to-left language (a language like persian or arabic that are right to left by default),
which way is better to set `text-align: right` and `direction: rtl` ?

1. globally, e.g:

   ```
    body * {
     direction: rtl;
     text-align: right;
      }
   ```
2. or on-demand, meaning wherever we wanted the html to be `direction: rtl` or `text-align: right` ?

the latter way (on-demand approach) may result in many lines of code, for example:

```
.btn {
      direction: rtl;
      text-align: right;
     }
.nav {
      direction: rtl;
      text-align: right;
     }
.footer {
      direction: rtl;
      text-align: right;
     }
```

etc.

am I right? which way is more standard?

Comment: Use `text-align: start/end` instead!

Comment: It's advised by the [relevant CSS specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-writing-modes-3/#direction) not to use `direction:rtl`, but to use `dir="rtl"` as an HTML attribute instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set `direction: rtl`, Text direction goes from right-to-left directly.

So, All you will do is set `direction: rtl` to body:

```
body {
  direction: rtl;
  text-align: right;
}
```

and all of `body` texts direction will go from right-to-left directly, unless you specify otherwise for specific element.

```css
body {
  direction: rtl;
}
.ltr {
  direction: ltr;
}
.left {
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>بسم الله الرحمن الرحيم</p>
  <p class='ltr'>In the name of Allah</p>
  <p class='left'>In the name of Allah</p>
  </body>
```